# cant find elements in scroll table using cypress

Tags: javascript, testing, automated-tests, cypress, e2e-testing

Im using cypress to check my website and I have a scroll table with over 500 clickable elements ,
I tried to click on some elements in my scroll table but Im getting "detach from dom" error.
Im trying to find the best way to access this elements.
what is the best way to access to this elements ? do i need to add to each one of the the
data-cy=attribute?
there is a way to scroll into specific ones? cant really find solutions to this problems.
thank you all!

Comment: Please add the code you tried to the question.

Comment: What is a "scroll table"?